# Как избежать дублирование сущностей при сохранении в БД?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, concurrency

Приложение на spring boot, есть события которые прилетают одновременно, например 5 событий и в них содержится какой-то person, в приложение есть список сущностей, в каждую нужно добавить копию person из события. Так как одновременно прилетают события, возникают случаи дублирования при создании копий сущностей, так как события выполняются в разных потоках одновременно. Как избежать такие проблемы? Блокировка на уровне БД, но если сильно нагружено приложение и пользователям нужно получить доступ к этим сущностям, в в этот момент прилетают события, таблица будет заблокирована и проблема производительности. Уменьшил транзакцию, раньше почти сразу открывалась, сделал чтобы при создании сущности сразу коммитилась. Как решаются такие проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял... То алгоритм примерно такой (подправите под себя) - вешаем на поле таблицы которое не должно дублироваться ключ `уникальный`. Пытаемся сделать `insert` в эту таблицу в это поле - в случае, если такое значение есть - ловим `exception` - в таком случае, если нам нужно, в приложении либо делаем `select id` либо получаем его из exception (если оно возвращается).
Например - таблица `users` - поле `username` уникальное. В один момент нам прилетает в разных потоках два одинаковых `username` - стартуют два одинаковых sql-запроса в БД на `insert` каждый в своей транзакции - какой-то из них пройдет первым, а второму выпадет исключение `duplicate unique key`.

Comment: Правильно поняли, но там не может быть уникального ключа, так как у меня есть список и вот у каждого элемента этого списка своя копия то, что пришло и вот из-за этого уникальности нет в таблице по этому полю. А если в аннотацию Transactional добавить уровень изоляции isolation REPEATABLE_READ?

Comment: Вы противоречите сами себе `так как одновременно прилетают события, возникают случаи дублирования при создании копий сущностей` . Понятие `дубль` означает две одинаковых сущности - осталось только решить по каким критериям понимать что они дублируют друг друга и вот на них и навесить признак уникальности. Например в случае совпадения полей `name`, `createdate`, `value` у двух сущностей вы считаете их дублями. Создаете `unique key` на совокупность этих трех полей, ну и далее как я написал ранее.

Comment: прилетает событие у которого есть уникальный идентификатор List<Item>, агрегат который слушает это событие имеет список, пусть будет List<Product>,  и у каждого Product есть List<Item> и вот из события нужно создать копию для каждого Product, используется одна сущность Item и для неё генерируется уникальный идентификатор, но также сохраняется уникальное поле из события, по которому и проверяю чтобы не дублировались. Проблема в том что, прилетает 2 события одновременно, находится нужный агрегат и каждый видит что ещё нет копии Item и создаёт ее, и в результате дубликация

Comment: Получается можно блокировку на уровне БД сделать, оптимистическую блокировку и вот ещё как можно, интересно если требуется производительность

Comment: у меня на БД запросы на `insert` прилетают десятки в секунду и никаких проблем с производительностью. я ловлю `exception unique key violation` в момент `insert returning id`, если его нет значит все норм, если есть значит запись уже существует - делаю `select id from ... where ...` - работает уже пару лет как без нареканий и тормозов